# Angular Routes :Multiple Outlets with path as string array

Tags: javascript, angular

In my angular9 application hundards of routes path are configured so Is there any way to use multiple outlets with single array of string path.

**current code:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'Data/:EntityID/:Date',
        component: MyFormComponent,children:[
            {
                path: '',
                loadChildren: () => import('../data-entry/data-entry.module').then(m => m.DataEntryModule)
            }
        ], 
    } ,
    { 
        path: 'Settings/:EntityID/:Date',
        component: MyFormComponent,children:[
            {
                path: '',
                loadChildren: () => import('../data-entry/data-entry.module').then(m => m.DataEntryModule)
            }
        ]
    }
...
];
    
export const routing = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

so is there any way to use same path as string array. Because in case of above way script is getting increase for same component for multiple path.

**something like**:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: ['Data/:EntityID/:Date','Settings/:EntityID/:Date',...],
        component: MyFormComponent,children:[
            {
                path: '',
                    loadChildren: () => import('../data-entry/data-entry.module').then(m => m.DataEntryModule)
            }
        ], 
    }
];
    
export const routing = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

Please suggest to me possible ways.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to the [Route](https://angular.io/api/router/Route) interface:

```
interface Route {
  path?: string
  pathMatch?: string
  matcher?: UrlMatcher
  component?: Type<any>
  redirectTo?: string
  outlet?: string
  canActivate?: any[]
  canActivateChild?: any[]
  canDeactivate?: any[]
  canLoad?: any[]
  data?: Data
  resolve?: ResolveData
  children?: Routes
  loadChildren?: LoadChildren
  runGuardsAndResolvers?: RunGuardsAndResolvers
}
```

The path is declared as of type string, so you cannot change that to an array of string. If you do so you will get this error:

```
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

Instead, try something like:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'Data/:EntityID/:Date',
        component: MyFormComponent,`children`:[
            {
                path: '',
                loadChildren: () => import('../data-entry/data-entry.module').then(m => m.DataEntryModule)
            }
        ], 
    } ,
    { 
        path: 'Settings/:EntityID/:Date',
        redirectTo: 'Data/:EntityID/:Date', pathMatch: 'full'
    }
...
];
```

This way you will not repeat at least the component and children part.

Comment: in above case using component and children same but redirect not working as `Settings/:EntityID/:Date`..it's using `Data/:EntityID/:Date`..how to change to path 'Settings/:EntityID/:Date'....i have different-2 content based on `Settings` and `Data' path but after change like above showing only data content in both case